# Implementing 'ReAuthentication' attribute in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Implementing a basic authorization and authentication layer is quite easy with ASP.NET MVC 4; it's all automatically generated with the 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application'-project template.

However, I'm tasked with implementing some controller actions that require re-authentication and I'm aiming for a maintainable solution. Simply put in a user story, I'm trying to implement the following:

1. User logs on;
2. User navigates to a controller (attributed with [Authorize]) action which renders a form view;
3. User performs a POST by submitting the form;
4. An authentication form appears in which the user needs to re-authenticate using his/her username and password;
5. If authentication is succesfull, proceed with handling the POST-request.

Note that 'reauthentication' does not have to alter the state of the current user session.

Obviously, there are many ways to implementing this, but I feel like an implementation which looks similiar to the following (pseudo) sample would suit my needs.

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class SpecialActionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SpecialForm() { return View(); }
    public ActionResult Succes() { return View(); }

    [HttpPost]
    [ReAuthenticate] /* <- Prompts user with reauthentication form before proceeding. */
    public ActionResult SpecialForm(SpecialFormModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            RedirectToAction("Succes");
        else
            return View(model);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I forgot to mention that any OAuth-related features are out of scope. External authentication is not an issue here and does not require support. In fact, with the current project I'm working on, all OAuth-related features are either removed or deactivated.

Comment: It seems odd to make someone *re-authenticate* when they are already authenticated, are you looking to implement something similar to UAC? I guess it adds another layer of security but I would imagine it could become a bit of a frustration for a user. Couldn't you use roles instead?

Comment: Hello James. You're making a good point about whether or not a certain solution is _user friendly_; I'm truly having doubts as to whether or not I would decide on something like this myself. Unfortunately, the specs dictate this feature and the client wants it so there's no way out of that one. Also, unfortunately, usage of roles will not have an impact because there aren't any. Thank you for your thoughts though!

Comment: This is definitely doable, I think the tricky part is going to be not affecting current authentication status. Would you only be re-authenticating once or would re-authentication be required everytime?

Comment: Re-authentication would be required every time. Do you have any helpful resources? Is there a base attribute class from which I could derive that'd help me get going?

Comment: yep, you are most likely going to want to derive your new attribute from [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). However, the problem you will have is forcing a re-authentication when the OP is already authenticated, I presume the internals are going to check for a stored authentication cookie. I was writing an answer up but it was mostly speculative because I had to no concrete evidence that it would work, I will have a think about this one and get back to you.

Comment: Hello James, I finally managed to implement a solution; check out my answer below. Feel free to comment on it; and thanks for your feedback and thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a combination of a custom [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and the `Session`. Override the [AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method and let all the default authentication take place but introduce your own extra check (for re-authentication) e.g.

```
public class RecurringAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute  
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var reauth = (bool?)httpContext.Session["ReAuthenticated"];
        var result = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext) && (reauth ?? false);
        httpContext.Session["ReAuthenticated"] = !result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

This should re-direct the user to the login page everytime they hit the action and they haven't re-authenticated. If the user has re-authenticated, we clear the session variable to force a login on the next request.

For this to work correctly, we need a hook to set the `ReAuthentication` session variable - I think the `LogOn` method in the `AccountController` would be the ideal place for this

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            Session["ReAuthenticated"] = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Then all that's left to do is decorate our controller actions

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomePrivateAction()
{
   ...
}

[RecurringAuthorize]
public ActionResult SomeSuperSecretAction()
{
   ...
}
```

You should find authorization will work as normal for any actions using the default `AuthorizeAttribute` and any actions decorated with the `RecurringAuthorizeAttribute` will be forced to login *everytime* they request the page, which includes page refreshes.

Comment: Hello James, thank you for your solution. I can definitely see benefits in this one compared to mine; especially the amount of code involved. But I do see one problem though: what happens to the execution of 'SomeSuperSecretAction' if it's a [HttpPost]-marked, model-accepting action? It will get lost or must be re-obtained through another Session variable, right? As far as I can see, it's great for "You must re-authenticate to view this form" style of reauthentication, but not for "Re-authenticate before we process your input"-style of reauthentication.

Comment: @RobWijkstra this wouldn't work (at least out of the box). The problem is when you attempt to `POST` the user is redirected to the login page - at that point the POST data is lost. There are ways around this, however, you would need to do something custom and most likely make use of the `Session` to store the POST data or alternatively using the [307 status code](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect) to preserve the POST data during a re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the hypothetical [ReAuthenticate]-attribute, but found myself relying on reflection too much. After putting some thought into a more manageable solution, I finally came up with the following:

**ReAuth class**

```
public sealed class ReAuth
{
    #region Constructor

    private ReAuth(Func<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult> onSuccessAction)
    {
        this.onSuccessAction = onSuccessAction;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public static members

    public static ReAuth CreateFor(HttpSessionStateBase httpSession, Func<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult> onSuccessAction)
    {
        httpSession[sessionKey] = new ReAuth(onSuccessAction);
        return GetFor(httpSession);
    }

    public static ReAuth GetFor(HttpSessionStateBase httpSession)
    {
        return httpSession[sessionKey] as ReAuth;
    }

    public static bool ExistsFor(HttpSessionStateBase httpSession)
    {
        return httpSession[sessionKey] as ReAuth != null;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public instance members

    public bool ReAuthenticated { get; set; }

    public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Handle()
    {
        if (ReAuthenticated)
            return onSuccessAction();
        else
            return new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult(
                new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
                {
                    { "Controller", "#" }, /* Replace '#' with the name of the controller that implements the re-authentication form... */
                    { "Action", "#" } /* Replace '#' with the name of the action on the aforementioned controller. */
                });
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private members

    private const string sessionKey = "reAuthenticationSessionKey";

    private readonly Func<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult> onSuccessAction;

    #endregion
}
```

**Implementation**

Suppose we have a hypothetical controller where the solution is applied:

```
public class AccountInfoController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    /* snip... */

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditAccountInfo(AccountInfo model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return ReAuth.CreateFor(Session, () => { return Success(); }).Handle();
        else
            return View(model);
    } 
}
```

...and, we need a controller (essentially, a 'dumb' copy of the *real* AccountController that does not tamper with the Forms Authentication User Session state) in which the re-authentication takes place.:

```
public class ReAuthController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    /* Snip... */
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ReAuth.GetFor(Session).ReAuthenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(model.User, model.Password);
            return ReAuth.Handle();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this is a manageable solution. It does rely a lot on storing objects into session state. (Especially the object state of the controller which implements the ReAuth-class) If anyone has additional suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: I'm glad you managed to find a solution that works for you, however, for me there is a bit too much going on here. Like I mentioned in my previous comments this can be achieved using a custom attribute which, in my opinion, is a neater solution - see my answer.